# Printing results from active_record to console

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I've got a console app I'm building that has the following code:

```
def self.List(table)
    if table == 'clients'
        puts "Showing all clients from the db"
        puts Client.all
    end
end
```

So if I call List('clients') it'll output the following:

```
Showing all clients from the db
```

But nothing else is printed out.  Now I have verified that there are records in the clients table and the database is defined so Active_record understands its scheme.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
puts Client.all
```

With

```
puts Client.all.inspect
```

`Client.all` returns an Array of `ActiveRecord::Relation` Class. You can see the contents of the array using `inspect` method.